# Is there a performance improvement with native images?

Tags: .net, performance

I've tried to measure it with a small [benchmark collection](http://benchmarks.codeplex.com/) and my own tests, but the results stay the same or even get worse. I also couldn't find any benchmark data on the web to this question, so here it is:

Is there really a performance improvement if I install native images of .NET assemblies? And if yes, in which areas and is it reasonable to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using native images will really only give you limited speed improvement, because functions will not have to be JIT compiled upon first entry to them.

Specifically, to quote [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28VS.80%29.aspx):

*Native images can provide performance improvements in two areas: improved memory use and reduced startup time*.

You will find that under the section *Determining When to Use Native Images*. There are some other times when you will notice improvements in speed, but those times are specific to certain scenarios, as mentioned in that article.